# Window Images in eclipse product not shown

Tags: java, eclipse, window, product, plugin.xml

I have defined all images from 16x16 px - 128x128 px (32 bit) in my eclipse product. They are being written into the plugin.xml of my UI

```
     <property
           name="windowImages"
           value="icons/16_32.gif,icons/32_32.gif,icons/48_32.gif,icons/64_32.gif,icons/128_32.gif">
     </property>
```

I now run the export wizard to create a executable. When i start the exe, the application shows a only a coloured red square icon both in explorer and alt+tab instead of my defined (and in build path exported) window images.

I have already tried using .png and .bmp instead, but it didn't work

Anyone already had the same issue?

Comment: Do you have the icons folder included in the binary build?

Comment: yeah, it's listed in bin.includes of the build.properties

Comment: You could check if they actually are in the .jar file of your plugin. Could you post your build.properties?

Comment: Hi mat,

source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.xml,\
               icons/,\
               splash.bmp,\
               ppm.hotfix.product

Comment: They are not in the .jar file of the plugin. I have linked them in my project, might that be the cause of error?

Comment: They definitely should be there. What do you mean by "linked in the project"?

Comment: Thanks @MatF ! I had to import the icon files by copying them into the project. Previously I just had them linked in the project, while they were lying somewhere outside of the project.

Comment: I posted this as an answer, as I think it was helpful. Please accept it :)

Comment: I have same problem , i check all what are menthined and it seem all fine except image icon in PNG format . Is it require to be in GIF format ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make sure that the images are actually in the specified folder and that they are included in the bin.include path of the build.properties file.